# On Catalina, Xcode 10 is "verified" every startup

Tags: macos-catalina, xcode10.2

[image: Verifying Xcode dialog]

I'm seeing my Xcode 10 (downloaded as I always do from the developer downloads website and not from the App Store) get verified EVERY single startup on Catalina 10.15.1

Does anyone know a workaround? I really regret upgrading to Catalina - like iOS13, it's not ready for prime time yet.

ALSO...

After running the the sim the first time (i.e. Xcode installs and runs the app in the sim), subsequent attempts to run the app in the sim bork because the same Verify process mentioned above runs for Xcode again (even though it's running the Xcode instance) and the debug connection times out, so it becomes impossible to run the app without removing the app first.

I would say at this point that Apple's security implementation in Catalina is thoroughly broken - would STRONGLY advise developers who work in a production environment with earlier Xcode versions to NOT upgrade from Mojave yet.

============== UPDATE ==============

Fixed with the Catalina 10.15.2 update

Comment: What sort of verification is this?

Comment: This is the verification popup you see all too often now on Catalina, the OS won't run the app until it passes

Comment: Sounds like it's not even related to Xcode, then?

Comment: Disagree, it's related to Xcode run on Catalina

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's not an appropriate forum for this, It's likely to me more useful here.